# Sudoku need help constructing visable matrix

Tags: java, matrix, sudoku

I'm trying to make Sudoku(just for fun), I wonder if there is any trick (graphics from api) or even by system.out.println(the noob way) a way to put my numbers when testing. At this momment im showing my numbrs in the matrix just like this :

```
System.out.print("["+x+"]"+"["+y+"]"+ matrix[x][y] +"        ");
```

So, yeah... If you please could tell me a place to start, i would appreciate a LOT!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print the array to the console, you can use a double `for` loop to iterate though the array and print all values, i.e.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        System.out.print("[" + matrix[x][y] + "]");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

You are printing one whole row of your Sudoku before starting a new line, for as may rows as your Sudoku has, which is probably 9.

edit: For creating a real UI, I would recommend looking into the Swing library which provides powerfull tools for UI creation.

Comment: what is at the swing library that i could probably use?

Comment: I would look into a proper tutorial as Swing is quite complex if you have never used it before, especially if you have never done anything UI related. [Maybe have a look at this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: just one more question. after I complete my project, is there a way I can export it as a android application or an app that can be usable by my friends in their computers?

Comment: To create an executable you can pack your classes to a .jar file. See [Creating a JAR File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) for more on that. I don't know about building android applications, but that's probably even more (Or equally) complex than building Swing UI.

Comment: If an answer in this thread has helped you, please consider accepting it. Also see [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for more information.